# Run node js on cmd

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to run the code in CMD and it just stuck,

I do not know what I should do to run the code in CMD.

I put the following code and it gets stuck: **node test.js**.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    res.writeHead(200);

    console.log("run");
    setTimeout(function(){

        console.log("done");
        res.end();

    }, 1000);

}).listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Comment: What does the command window say? What OS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

The code executes, but it does not exit as it starts listening to the connections.

---

To be exact, the code you gave creates HTTP server and listens on the port set by variable PORT (`%PORT%` in Windows, or `$PORT` in Unix).

If you do not know the concept of environment variables, replace last line with:

`}).listen(8080);`

Once your code is running, open the browser on same machine and go to: http://localhost:8080 you shall get the blank page, but in your Node console you will see `run` and `done` messages printed.

---

That is what your code does, if you want to learn basics about Node.js I suggest trying this [interactive tutorial](http://nodeschool.io/#workshoppers)